# Svn Commit failed. HTTP status 413 'Request Entity Too Large

Tags: svn

When I try to commit files up to 100 kb (approximately) SVN server returns me the following error:

> svn: Unexpected HTTP status 413 'Request Entity Too Large' on '/svn/!svn/txr/17-v/SecurePack/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/css/bootstrap.css'

I'm using Apache2 server on Ubuntu 15. To avoid problems related to svn update limits i set a LimitXMLRequestBody 0 in my dav_svn.conf but the error persists:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /svn
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
  LimitXMLRequestBody 0
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: Did you try LimitRequestBody (without XML)? Also, mod-info might be useful to understand what settings are really applied to your location

Comment: I solved using LimitRequestBody 0  instead of LimitXMLRequestBody 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `LimitRequestBody 0` instead of `LimitXMLRequestBody`.

Comment: I already tried to use LimitRequestBody 0 in dav_svn.conf, instead of LimitXMLRequestBody 0. But the error persists.

Comment: Did you restarted server after changing configuraiton? May be you have LimitRequestBody configured in other place? Do you have proxy between client and the server?

Comment: You are right. I have not solve the problem restarting Apache2 server but after rebooting the O.S. svn works well. Now i am able to commit without size limits.